# Sampling error for proportion with finite population - which correction to use?

Tags: measurement-error, survey-sampling

I am trying to calculate sampling error for a questionnaire that was answered by some of the participants in a program (say about . I want to calculate the sampling error for the proportion of the respondents that answered "yes" to a "yes/no" question.
I have seen some sites that use this formula for the calculation:

```
Sampling Error = Z * (p(1-p)/n)^0.5 * ((N-n)/(N-1))^0.5
```

where
Z stands for the Z score for the selected confidence level,
p stands for the expected proportion (the sample proportion is used)
N is the size of the population (all the program participants in my example)
n is the number of respondents.

I have also seen discussed a different formula:

```
Sampling Error = Z * (p*(1–p)/n)^0.5 * (1–(n/N)^0.5)
```

The two formulas yeald very different solutions. My friend ChatGPT says the first formula is more conservative but there are contexts where the second formula is a good choice too, but cannot explain what the difference is, what the pros and cons are for each formula or which situations would call for using one or the other.
Could anyone shed light on the subject?
Many thanks.

Comment: Well $1-\frac{n}{N} = \frac{N-n}{N}$, so the results should be essentially the same for larger values of $N$. In general, $N-1$ vs. $N$ in the denominator arises from an unbiased estimator vs. maximum likelihood estimator. Both are reasonable and are essentially the same for larger values of $N$.

Comment: Your `(1–(n/N)^0.5)`  i.e. $1- \sqrt{\frac nN}$ looks as if it has the brackets in the wrong place and should have been $\sqrt{1-\frac nN} = \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N}}$  which will be close to the "[finite population correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Finite_population_correction_(FPC))" of $\sqrt{\frac {N-n}{N-1}}$ when calculating the standard error of the sample mean.

Comment: I see what you mean. But [this site](https://www.educba.com/sampling-error-formula/) has the 1 clearly outside the brackets. You aren't suggesting something clearly written in the INTERNET could be wrong, are you?